# polar graphs and investigation

Tags: trigonometry, functions, graphing-functions, plane-curves

I am new to polar graphs and I am trying to investigate some certain cases:

1. What happens when you change the $b$ value to different positive integers in polar equations of the forms: $r=b\cos(\theta)$ and $r=b\sin(\theta)$?
2. What happens when you keep $b$ constant, but change the $n$ value to different positive integers in polar equations of the forms: $r=b\cos(n\theta)$, $r=b\sin(n\theta)$?
3. What happens when you keep $b$ and $n$ constant, but change the $a$ value to different integers in polar equations of the forms: $r=a+b\cos(n\theta)$, $r=a+b\sin( n \theta)$?

Thanks.

Comment: First question: did you try a few examples with specific values of $b$, $n$, $a$? If not, then try them!

Comment: If you don't have a graphic software you can use [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=polarplot+r%3D++cos[2+theta]) to experiment.

Comment: Just play around! Don't be afraid...

Answer (score 1):

As other said, the best answer is to experiment. Wolfram Alpha was already mentioned, but I'll point out that [fooplot](http://www.fooplot.com) has clean and intuitive interface, easy ways to zoom in/out, combine multiple plots, [share plots](http://fooplot.com/plot/kxh1kgw0yz) and so on.

[image]

(I have no affiliation with fooplot, in case you wonder)